# Qual o real incentivo da medalha "Disciplinado"?

Tags: debate, medalhas

Essa dúvida já me corrói desde a primeira vez que eu vi essa medalha no SO.com mas nunca tinha perguntado ou ido atrás do real motivo.

Agora com o SOPT decidi perguntar já que com certeza muitos membros e futuros membros daqui terão a mesma dúvida, e ninguém precisará buscar a resposta no metão (acredito que tenha lá, não procurei).

Gostaria de saber qual o real incentivo que esta medalha sugere:

> #### Disciplinado
>
> Exclui a própria publicação com uma pontuação de 3 ou superior.

Ou seja, em que caso o ato de alguém excluir sua própria publicação que teoricamente foi útil para a comunidade é algo benéfico?

Comment: @bfavaretto _peer pressure_ é exatamente o contrário: `Pressão dos colegas; Excluiu a própria publicação com pontuação de -3 ou menos `

Comment: Ah, confundi as medalhas! :P

Comment: Corrigindo então, agora com a medalha certa em mente: se alguém exclui uma publicação com +3 é porque a considera incorreta (pelo menos quando ocorreu comigo foi assim). As pessoas dão upvotes em material incorreto/ruim mais do que você imagina...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isso pode acontecer - e ser benéfico para o site - se sua pergunta estiver fora do escopo do site, mal-formulada (por qualquer motivo) ou for uma duplicata. Ainda que perguntas desses tipos não sejam adequadas, é comum ver pessoas a votar positivamente nelas. Principalmente no último caso.

Acho que a medalha serve para demonstrar que você preza mais pela qualidade do conteúdo do site do que por sua pontuação.

**Edição:** A medalha também vale para respostas. Também é possível que uma pessoa ofereça uma resposta errada, ou com muitas falhas, mas que mesmo assim tenha pontuado positivamente. Nesse caso acho a medalha ainda mais merecida, pois a meu ver respostas erradas com alta pontuação ou marcada como corretas podem causar dores de cabeça maiores que perguntas com problemas.

Comment: E realmente acontece bastante do pessoal votar em resposta "bonita mas errada".